# C# AutoMap - the output results of an object/array to model or list - Using the AutoMapper reference

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I'm a beginner at C#. How would I output the results of this object type to a model list. Here is the code:

```
var getGroups = Customers.GetGroups(true);

        if (getGroups == null || !getGroups.Any())
        {
            return new List<GetGroupsModel>();
        }

return _mapper.Map<List<GetGroupsModel>>(getGroups);
```

The var getGroups returns the following:

```
getGroups {Client.Customers.CustomerSummary[2]}
        [0] {Client.Customers.CustomerSummary}
             Desc          value0
             DescFieldNm   value0
             Name          value0
             NameFieldNm   value0
             NbrContacts   value0
             NbrContactsFieldNm   value0
        [1] {Client.Customers.CustomerSummary}
             Desc          value1
             DescFieldNm   value1
             Name          value1
             NameFieldNm   value1
             NbrContacts   value1
             NbrContactsFieldNm   value1
```

The Model is:

```
 public class GetGroupsModel
    {
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int NbrContacts { get; set; }
    }
```

After trying this way, I receive error at the line (return _mapper.Map>(getGroups);):
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Have you checked some samples like this https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/automapper-in-c-sharp/? Could you post all the code and add some dummy data instead of using some "Get" calls?

Comment: Your model is missing some objects that are shown in your return results